# Convert Text value of column name to Column in a query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to dynamically fetch the value of column named 'abc' using the text that is deduced from the decode function. Decode function is returning the text value of the column, that is 'abc' but not the underlying value dynamically. Is there a way to do this ?

```sql
SELECT LOWER(DECODE('METRIC','METRIC','abc','MODEL','xyz','COUNTRY','US')) as abc FROM table_test
```

Expected result :

```
abc
---
1.2 
1.5
1.6
1.7
```

table_test :

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated my post. Thanks!

Comment: What is the source of input values `METRIC`, `MODEL`, and `COUNTRY` ?

Comment: Those are just reference variables. If you just run the select statement "SELECT LOWER(DECODE('METRIC','METRIC','abc','MODEL','xyz','COUNTRY','US'))" output will be 'abc' but when I run it on the table, I want that 'abc' to be considered as a column (since that column abc exists in the table) instead of the text value and give me the corresponding values from that column.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use columns as the values in `DECODE`, you may always write a regular `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE metric WHEN 'METRIC'  THEN abc
                WHEN 'MODEL'   THEN xyz
                WHEN 'COUNTRY' THEN US END AS output
FROM table_test;
```